# Linking two object files together causes segmentation fault 11

Tags: c, linker, segmentation-fault, extern

I am experimenting with externs and various methods of linking to better understand the linking process.

I have three files:

**foo.c:**

```
#include "foo.h"
int a = 4;
```

**test.c:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "foo.h"
int main(int, char**);
int mymain();

int mymain() {
    main(0, 0);
    printf("test\r\n");
    return 0;
}
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    printf("extern a has %d\r\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

**foo.h:**

```
extern int a; // defined in foo.c
```

If I build each file together and link at compile time using gcc like this:

```
gcc *.c -o final.bin
```

I can execute final.bin as:

```
./final.bin
```

and get expected output

```
extern a has 4
```

However, if I compile (but don't link) test.c and foo.c separately, then try and link the object files together at runtime to produce a binary, I get a segmentation fault 11 (which from what I can gather is some generic memory corruption bug like a normal segfault(?)

Here is my makefile I'm using to compile and link separately. Note I am specifying my own entry point and linking against libc to get printf()...

```
all: test.o foo.o
    @echo "Making all..."
    ld test.o foo.o -o together.bin -lc -e _mymain

test.o: test.c
    @echo "Making test..."
    gcc -c test.c -o test.o

foo.o: foo.c
    @echo "Making foo..."
    gcc -c foo.c -o foo.o
```

Output when running 'together.bin':

```
./together.bin 
extern a has 4
test
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Perhaps my function signature for 'mymain' is wrong? My guess is that something is wrong with my 'myentry' usage.

Also, if anyone has any recommendations on good books for how linkers and loaders work, I am certainly in the market for one. I've heard mixed things about 'Linkers and Loaders', so I'm waiting on more opinions before I invest the time in that book in particular.

Thanks for any help on this... My understanding of linkers is sub-par to say the least.

Comment: There's a lot more difference in those two ways of building the program than just "linking the object files together" vs "linking the source files together"!

Comment: The function pointed to by the `-e` linker option has more responsibilities than the standard C `main`. The entry point is normally linked in from the C runtime, and it is responsible for setting up and tearing down support structures for your executable, in tight coupling with the dynamic linker. You're probably crashing somewhere in ld.so because it expected some structure to exist by shutdown. You can verify that with gdb and checking the stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

Unless if you have a good reason to do so, just use gcc to link:

```
$ gcc test.o foo.o "-Wl,-e,_mymain" -o ./final.bin; ./final.bin 
extern a has 4
test
```

gcc calls ld---though, with a few more arguments than you are providing in your example. If you want to know exactly how gcc invokes ld, use the `-v` option.  Example:

```
$ gcc -v test.o foo.o "-Wl,-e,_mymain" -o ./final.bin
Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.38)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -dynamic -arch x86_64 -macosx_version_min 10.12.0 -syslibroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk -o ./final.bin test.o foo.o -e _mymain -lSystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/8.0.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a
```

Comment: Thanks for your response - this solved my problem. I am assuming something gcc invokes the linker with somehow does this... I would like to know why. I'll do more reading on linkers when I get the chance. I'd accept your solution as the answer but I have less than 15 rep, so I can't do that.